# Result of one column of a row to be used as input to the next row of a column in PL SQL

Tags: plsql

I have three columns
Added premium A
Deleted premium D
Net premium N(as on today)

Intial Premium I= N-A+D is the formula
Now the question is Over a period so many addition and deletion of premium happened.

Ex The below is the table where addition and deletion happened

| Policy | Subpolicy | N | A | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | b | 5 | 0 | 2 |

So to find Initial Premium (I)
Over all policy level 5-3+2=4

Now the problem is to find sub policy level
I=5-3+0=2
Now I have to use the above 2 as input to the next N
I=2-0+2=4

Comment: Please read [ask] Edit the question and show the DDL and sample data in a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

ultimately it should be like

`(N of first subpolicy) - SUM(A) +SUM(D)`

Since you have provided very abstract question, here is my answer in abstract way,

```
select 
(t2.N - sum(t1.A) +sum(t1.S)) as initial_premium 
from 
TABLE t1, 
(select * from TABLE where [condition to get the first subpolicy] ) t2 
where 
t1.Policy=t2.Policy and t1.Policy=<policy_number>
```